# Apache2 pointing /example to another local ip web server

Tags: debian, apache-http-server, proxy, reverse-proxy

I have an apache2 server running on 192.168.1.2 and accessible from outside using publicip/.

What i'd like to do is redirect publicip/example1 to another local ip (let's say 192.168.1.3) and publicip/example2 to another one (192.168.1.4),...

I tried to follow instructions here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441227/apache-using-reverse-proxy-and-run-local-website

So i made a site.conf which look like that :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName mysite.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mysite.com

    <Directory /var/www/html/mysite.com>
            require all granted
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    <Location /example1 >
            ProxyPass http://192.168.1.3:80/
            ProxyPassReverse http://192.168.1.3:80/
    </Location>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

With this conf, i can access mysite.com at root, but when i try to connect mysite.com/example1, it doesn't work and gives me this error :

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

Apache error log says :

```
[Tue Feb 14 15:46:00.894989 2017] [proxy:warn] [pid 1993] [client XX.XX.XX.XX:51795] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /example1. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Tue Feb 14 15:46:06.938982 2017] [proxy:warn] [pid 1995] [client XX.XX.XX.XX:51804] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /example1. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
```

What am i doing wrong please ?

Thanx !

Comment: `mod_proxy` isn't loaded. Enable `a2enmod proxy` and reload apache. Change `ProxyPass http://192.168.1.3:80/` to `ProxyPass "/examle1" http://192.168.1.3:80/`. Do the same for `ProxyPassReverse`

Comment: Thanx will try that !